# How to install docker-compose on Linux RHEL 6.6?

Tags: python, linux, docker, docker-compose, rhel6

Any idea how to install docker-compose on Linux RHEL.

I followed below steps

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install -y python-pip
sudo pip install docker-compose
sudo yum upgrade python*
```

I am getting below message when trying to check its version (docker-compose -version)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import errors
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 10, in <module>
    from docker.errors import APIError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/docker/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import DockerClient, from_env
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models.containers import ContainerCollection
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 874
    for network in networks}
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea about this issue or I make mistake in installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL 6 is not recommended and not supported for Docker use.

There was many addition made to recent version of Linux kernels that allows Docker, but they are missing on RHEL 6 because it is designed to be an enterprise system with very long term support (10 years).

Simply put it is too old, and [Red Hat themselves aren't porting Docker on it](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1378023).

Comment: Is it not recommended for RHEL 6.6 or they don't have any docker-compose for it?

Comment: The resolution section from the Red Hat link in my reply states:

_The version of docker that is maintained and supported by Red Hat is only available on RHEL 7 and above_. 

From experience, it is a matter of minutes to get it working on RHEL7..

Answer (score 7):

RHEL6 and Centos6 most commonly use ancient docker-1.7.1 as installed with yum. It's only compatible with [docker-compose-1.5.2](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.5.2) (or older), for which you can still (as of 2018) download a compiled binary:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.5.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

ldd /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffaed8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9d5e0c3000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9d5dead000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d5db19000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d5e2c7000)
```

Remember, your docker-compose.yml is limited to [syntax version 1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/). Although that link says docker 1.7.1 is unsupported, it will work; I use it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the problem is with the installation. Still, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) web-page.

According to the error you are getting, seems like there's some issue with the file */usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py*.

Why don't you check if there had been some modifications in that file. 
Otherwise you can clean install the docker-compose using the github repository.

Comment: I cleaned and installed the docker-compose using the github repository. "docker-compose version" works. But when tried "docker-compose up", it started giving me error that you need at least 1.9.0 or greater version of docker. I installed docker using "yum install docker-io" and it installed 1.7V of docker. Don't know how to have 1.9 or greater version of docker?

Comment: Then it might be the reason that zlig mentioned. RHEL 6 might not be supported by docker anymore. what you can try is, use docker machine.

Install docker/docker-machine on a separate machine (with RHEL 7+) and create this machine as remote host using that. 
you can also create a VM and install Docker on it.